# Asynchronious CSS load with MVC5 Bundles

Tags: css, asynchronous, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, bundles

I was reading about asynchronous CSS loading
[here](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS)
and I was wondering if it is possible to use that kind of behaviour in MVC5 bundles.

What I want to achieve is multiple bundled CSS files downloaded in a non-blocking way (meaning faster loading time of my page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method on the `Styles` helper where you can set your own tag format.

```
@Styles.RenderFormat("<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"preload\" as=\"style\"/>",
                     "~/Path/To/My/Bundle")
```

Answer (score 0):

For full working solution I'm using the answer I marked as acceptance to this question, but I've added one more thing to it to make it work 100%

```
onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"
```

so working example is:

C# file:

```
public const string StyleRenderFormat = "<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"preload\" as=\"style\" onload=\"this.rel='stylesheet'\"/>";
```

cshtml file:

```
@Styles.RenderFormat(BundleConfig.StyleRenderFormat, "~/myCssBundleName")
```